# How do I include CC using emails from a particular column RANGE

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do I modify the code below to CC emails from a specific column range. Lets just say column H. I used `msg.To = sh.Range().Value` for the normal distributed list in another column as you can see below

My version of excel = Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2307) 64-bit. Windows 10 Enterprise

```vb
Sub Send_Bulk_Mails()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Recipient Input")
Dim i As Integer

Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object

Set OA = CreateObject("outlook.application")

PathFileName = "G:\WIN\..."

Dim last_row As Integer
last_row = Application.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

For i = 2 To last_row
    If sh.Range("G" & i).Value <> "Sent" Then

    Set msg = OA.CreateItemFromTemplate(PathFileName)
    
    msg.To = sh.Range("E" & i).Value
    
    msg.Subject = "We need your support"
    
    
    With msg
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "cap..@yahoo.com"
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "....", sh.Range("C" & i).Value & " " & sh.Range("B" & i).Value)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "....", sh.Range("D" & i).Value)
        .Display
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Application.SendKeys "%s"
        
    End With
    
    
    ' msg.Body = Body
    
    ' replace place holders
    ' msg.Send
    
    sh.Range("G" & i).Value = "Sent"
    
    End If

Next i

MsgBox "All emails have been sent"

End Sub
```

I expect excel to pick up emails from a particular column and include these in the CC. Each email should correspond with the CC email in the same row

Comment: Do you mean like `msg.CC = sh.Range("H" & i).Value` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your code work you can do the same as `msg.To = sh.Range("E" & i).Value`. Just make a line like after this with `msg.Cc = sh.Range("H" & i).Value` if column H is the same range of those to be on copy on the e-mail.